# Typescript Generics Perserve Types

Tags: typescript, generics

I have two Types defined as:

```js
type Foo<N extends string, T extends any> = { [name in N]: T };
type Bar<N extends string, T extends any> = { name: N; obj: T };
```

And I have a function defined as:

```js
function makeFooFromBar<N extends string, T extends any>(params: Array<Bar<N, T>>): Foo<N, T> {
    const ret: any = {};

    for (const { name, obj } of params) {
        ret[name] = obj;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

What this is supposed to do is:

```js
const foo = makeFooFromBar([
    { name: 'abc', obj: 10 },
    { name: 'def', obj: 20 },
]);

// has value 10
foo.abc;

// has value 20
foo.def;
```

So far, this works fine, but it only works, when `obj` is always the same type. For example, this does not work:

```js
const foo = makeFooFromBar([
    { name: 'abc', obj: 10 },
    { name: 'def', obj: 20 },
    { name: 'xyz', obj: 'abc' }, // error, string can not be assigned to number
]);
```

Is there a way to make this work? Also I need the original Types to be preserved, so `foo.abc` and `foo.def` need to be `number` and `foo.xyz` needs to be a `string` (it is not good when all three of them are `number | string`).

Comment: What are types Def and Ref?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to adjust these to the types Foo and Bar. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to compile by explicitly supplying generic types:

```
const foo2 = makeFooFromBar<'abc' | 'def' | 'xyz', 10 | 20 | 'abc'>([
    { name: 'abc', obj: 10 },
    { name: 'def', obj: 20 },
    { name: 'xyz', obj: 'abc' },
]);
// const foo2: Foo<"abc" | "def" | "xyz", "abc" | 10 | 20>
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAOShAHsCA7AJgZyn2ACcBLbAcwBooAVAPigF4oBvKAbWwEMBbaBSjIAugC56UAL4BuAFChIUAEI8SKNJhwEipCjXpNWHXgInIZUOACMAVhLrT5cgGYBXbAGNgZONih8PADWEPBwMCRwfKrqqBhYeITE5FS0jAAUYGr8+BIAgiQkPCCIMShpDAwAlBJh5YbsclDNUJ5+xFAkEMASPNggLOyyck0tLnAkUOlt2B0m-BC0NrbSVi5QWUV8+FWNLfud3dwLIoPL8vtSI-tdwG4k-rfyV3IzHeNwg4EhYRFRMelOKNmvMzFAAOQ8ayecFLOwSACMAAZpNRgewoKYIBJwbgIC5YVZ4VAAEwoqRokRVZwAehpUAAFjxCAA3HgAGzc0GRrgQADooZ5afSmayOVzSUjeXA+XiXM43sAoB8SV9gqEEH9ompEJDoeCoAAfCFyg3G8HoEAAL0JyKNkvtephDEB6NB2IhgsJy0R5LR+3dONNcPsDopbsxCxxlptIZxXtRUDpaEKE1oyX0rT6mLgSus0GZ+DIlGwEFwUGAn2wbj4+ZIcip8iAA)

But this is very annoying to use.

---

Another option is to explicitly generically type the entire array so TypeScript won't infer types too soon:

```
function makeFooFromBar<N extends string, T, A extends Array<Bar<N, T>>>(params: A): Foo<N, T> {
    ...
}

const foo2 = makeFooFromBar([
    { name: 'abc', obj: 10 },
    { name: 'def', obj: 20 },
    { name: 'xyz', obj: 'abc' },
]);
// const foo2: Foo<string, unknown>
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAOShAHsCA7AJgZyn2ACcBLbAcwBooAVAPigF4oBvKAbWwEMBbaBSjIAugC56UAL4BuAFChIUAEI8SKNJhwEipCjXpNWHXgInIZUOACMAVhLrT5cgGYBXbAGNgZONih8PADWEPBwMCRwfKrqqBhYeITE5FS0dLQAgpoJOhkkJDwgiDEoaQzlABRgavz4EhkAlBJhpYbsclCdUJ5+xFAkEMASPNggLOyych1dLnAkUBU92H0m-BC0NrbSVi5Q1QV8+A3tXaf9g9xrIuOb8qdSU6cDwG4k-s-yD3JLfbNw44EQmEIlEYhVONNOqszFAAOQ8ayeWEbOwSACMAAZpNRIewoKYIBJYbgIC5kVZUVAAExYqQ4kQNZwAeiZUAAFjxCAA3HgAGzc0ExrgQADoEZ5mayOdy+QLqRjhXARSSXM4fsAoH8qQDgqEECDompwbjoYS4eLyZt0bScadTUSVZbKTTsSb8WsiegQAAvJ32c2I2GuhnyIA)

But you can see it screws up the type of `T` for some reason.

---

We can move the inference to the return type, which seems to help a bit:

```
function makeFooFromBar<A extends Array<Bar<any, any>>>(params: A): A extends Array<Bar<infer N, infer T>> ? Foo<N, T> : never {
    ...
}

const foo2 = makeFooFromBar([
    { name: 'abc', obj: 10 },
    { name: 'def', obj: 20 },
    { name: 'xyz', obj: 'abc' },
]);
// const foo2: Foo<string, string | number>
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAOShAHsCA7AJgZyn2ACcBLbAcwBooAVAPigF4oBvKAbWwEMBbaBSjIAugC56UAL4BuAFChIUAEI8SKNJhwEipCjXpNWHXgInIZUOACMAVhLrT5cgGYBXbAGNgZONih8PADWEPBwMCRwfKrqAIKaWHiEsSQkPCCIMYg82CC0OSAMRQAUYGr8+BKxAJRVCdrJqemZaogULhAkwrTtnYZMAPywCCi0jFAS2BAAbn1sclCLUJ5+xFAkEMASBSzssnILSy5wXcUr2Gsm-BC0NrbSVi5QZWl8+NXsh0tLG8Dc1yJdnd5N8pAdvr83CR-L95GC5Oc1sc4LtAiEwhEojFipwvuwoKYIBIAOQ8ayeYm3OwSACMAAZpNQ8VczFBibgIC5KVZqVAAEwMqRMkTVZwAejFUAAFjxCNMeAAbNzQemuBAAOjJnnFkplcsVyv5dLVcHVHJczkRwCgyL5qOCoQQmOiahxzIJ1xJWu5d1pgqZ3xZRLZ5p9vIFjPdhJJ6BAAC8w-Y2d7IyL5EA)

---

It's also possible to do this with very fancy complicated types to get every key and value as a type, but not so sure about it...
[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAOShAHsCA7AJgZyn2ACcBLbAcwBooAVAPigF4oBvKAbWwEMBbaBSjIAugC56UAL4BuAFChIUAEI8SKNJhwEipCjXpNWHXgInIZUOACMAVhLrT5C8NACyPANYR4cGCTg+VRIAJQh8AFcAG2BEAEFNLDxCEggeXDhsKJAVNUQebBBaApAGThEjKASMJJ1gxAoAMwgSYVomlsNyqAB+WAQUWkYoMTkocf6kNjGJ2c4AaSghbxA4RqrxKoWRRO1Ceo7W5GLCpj7UCWwIADcW+VmpTgBRdABjKIjcCEQVtaraX7rcoMES0aazOaLZYQVbrOKbOLbXbJXLqErtbDNVrDPqOS43O4zcaPF7vT7fQH-KCU4EVZyNCLYV7AMiZKB8Lw+BD+QL1apaFGpdKZbKo-KFE6lYEACjAan4+AkcQAlBIPN5fDygmowpEYvEmOCJq9MsQoKlgBIAApqFk8KKIdVcvwBbWhcLRWJxBiVNiyOREqCNOCtaUm7Bmkz8CC0Gy2aRWdZykgK5XsQOzC3caNQHiESmKCB-C07Vhx+4TKQBzMQYAREjYc213OEJ2a13BXWeg3yKtycNm4NwFjsznt3lqaWcQNRsxQADkPGsr3nsbsEgAjAAGaTUGdQUwQCTzr6NVdWddQABMO6ke52eagA+AyucAHo31AABaP672iLQNuchDgAdEurzvp+P6EH+HzQDewEICBp7OM+QYIFeI4chq3IdpO06zLOR4LuB55xput57oRB7Rsep5kZeN67vuh7HugIAAF4MfYJHLvOzEPoQz6vnIQA)